# Html: change image by clicking on the same image

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

guys, I want to choose image by clicking on the current image.

This is my code. `url` contains default image. I want  to change my current image clickable and when use click on it, he can select new image. Is this possible without `<input type="file">` ?

```js
    onFileChanged(event) {
 
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
            reader.onload = (event) => { // 
                this.url = event.target.result;
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <img [src]="url" style="bordered:5px; double-black; border-radius: 8px; max-height: 200px; max-width: 390px; border: 2px solid #ddd;"> 
</div>
```

Comment: at least you need hidden file input field to obtain the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a hidden file input field

```
<input type="file" hidden  (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #file>
<img [src]="url" *ngIf="url" (click)="file.click()" width="200" />
```

for working example check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsgzsp)